# Not able to set boolean variable to false, once firebase throws an error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app for my uni students where they have to verify their official email Id during sign up. Currently, I am hitting firebase to check if everything they entered after @ matches the uni email value in firebase. (Checking if domain matches string stored in firebase). I seem to be doing something wrong in terms of setting the boolean value.

The way I want it to work -

When I press the next button, call a function **getEmailIsUni** that basically does the following:

1. Set uniExists = true, if firebase retrieved documents and then push
   to next viewController.
2. Set uniExists = false, if firebase threw an error and change the
   background colour of current viewController to red.

But, for some reason, value only sets itself to true properly. If firebase fails to retrieve documents or if there are no documents, then it does not seem to set the uniExists variable to false.

```
class RegistrationController2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    let regSup1VC = RegistrationSupplementoryController() 

    var uniExists: Bool! {
        didSet{
            if uniExists{
                navigationController?.pushViewController(regSup1VC, animated: true)
            } else {
                view.backgroundColor = .red
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureViews()
        formValidation()
    }


    @objc func handleNext(){
        getEmailIsUni()
    }


    func getEmailIsUni(){
        let emailText = regView2.emailTextField.text
        var emailDomain:String?
        if let range = emailText?.range(of: "@") {
            let email = emailText?[range.upperBound...].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            emailDomain = email
        }
        Firestore.firestore().collection("university").whereField("syntax", isEqualTo: emailDomain!).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("There was an error getting the documents or no documents available. ", error.localizedDescription)
                self.uniExists = false
            }

            for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                let docValues: [String:Any] = document.data()
                let uniName = (docValues["name"] as? String)!
                self.regSup1VC.nameOfUni = uniName
                self.uniExists = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error Firebase throws here?

Comment: @jms Thanks for replying. Problem is not the error. I want variable to be set to false if no document exists. If document exists, then I want it to be set to true.

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect this intent. Your check for `if let error = error` only checks if firebase reported a failure when executing your request. An absence of document will not give an error (I think it will be nil)

Comment: @jms Yea that's what I was thinking as well while replying to your comment. So the error is only if firebase itself had a problem connecting with the app?

Comment: Yes...network, authentication or other errors between the firebase-sdk you use and the remote database which firebase can detect.

Comment: @jms ok thanks for confirming. I guess i need to use "if document exists" then to evaluate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the email is unique replace

```
for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
    let docValues: [String:Any] = document.data()
    let uniName = (docValues["name"] as? String)!
    self.regSup1VC.nameOfUni = uniName
    self.uniExists = true
}
```

with

```
if let document = querySnapshot?.documents.first { 
    let docValues = document.data()
    self.regSup1VC.nameOfUni = docValues["name"] as! String
    self.uniExists = true
} else {
    self.uniExists = false
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realised that error messages are only if app is unable to contact the server. Thanks for your answer.